# Trying to show children of items (with Lock child relationship = true) in a bucket

Tags: pipelines, buckets

I am trying to let children show up when you search and open a item that is in a bucket (Lock child relationship is set to true).

This blog post describes this:
http://www.goblinrockets.com/2015/03/31/sitecore-managing-children-of-items-stored-in-a-bucket/

Basically what he does is opening a small local content tree showing just the opened item and its children.

However the `uiLaunchResult` pipeline never seems to get used in Sitecore 9.2. Has there been a breaking change and if so how is the new pipeline called?

Comment: I am not understanding your question here, `uiLaunchResult` is still in use as part of Sitecore.Buckets.config for Sitecore 9.2

Comment: The config is there but its never called from code so I think they removed it but they didn't clean up everything.